# React: Await useReducer dispatch before navigating away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-router, react-hooks

I have a function that is called in an `onClick` handler.
It saves data, then navigates away using e.g. react-router:

```
async function saveAndExit() {
  await dispatchSave(data);
  navigateAway();
}
```

The problem is that `dispatchSave` cannot easily be awaited:

```
// react hooks useReducer
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

// problem: dispatch doesn't return a promise
function dispatchSave(data) {
  dispatch({ type: 'save', payload: data })
})
```

What is the correct way to handle this when using `dispatch`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use traditional callbacks

```
function dispatchSave(data, callback) {
  dispatch({ type: 'save', payload: {data, callback} })
})
```

Then

```
async function saveAndExit() {
  dispatchSave(data, navigateAway);
}
```

In your middleware (Saga/Thunk), after the save operation is completed, you can call `payload.callback()` in synchronous way.

Comment: While this terminology seems redux related(?), I can see how it applies to hooks. I will first see if there is something that doesn't require callback functionality inside the reducer, and will accept this answer if no simpler solution or other improvement advice comes in. Thanks!